# Print line after nth occurrence of a match

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression

I am looking to display the line 4598 in the following file. Effectively I want to display the line AFTER the nth occurrence of a match. In this case, the line after the 3rd occurrence of `<Car>`. How do I go about this?

```
<Car>
10456
</Car>
<Car>
70192
</Car>
<Car>
4598
</Car>
```

Comment: While it might be possible to achieve what you want using `sed`, `awk`, or even `grep`, it's advisable to make use of a XML parser.

Comment: XML was only used for the example, text may be any format

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
awk -v n=3 '/<Car>/ && !--n {getline; print; exit}'
```

Or:

```
awk '/<Car>/ && ++n == 3 {getline; print; exit}'
```

To pass the search pattern as a variable:

```
var='<car>'
PATTERN="$var" awk -v n=3 '
  $0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"] && ++n == 3 {getline; print; exit}'
```

Here using `ENVIRON` instead of `-v` as `-v` expands backslash-escape sequences and backslashes are often found in regular expressions (so would need to be doubled with `-v`).

GNU `awk` 4.2 or above lets you assign variables as [strong typed regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants). As long as its POSIX mode is not enabled (for instance via the `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable, you can do:

```
# GNU awk 4.2 or above only, when not in POSIX mode
gawk -v n=3 -v pattern="@/$var/" '
  $0 ~ pattern && ++n == 3 {getline; print; exit}'
```

Comment: How to pass the search pattern also as a variable in the above command

Comment: @WanderingMind, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a perl one:

```
perl -ne 'print && exit if $c==3; $c++ if /<Car>/;' file
```

With GNU `grep`, you can also parse its output like:

```
grep -A 1 -m 3 '<Car>' file | tail -n 1
```

From `man grep`:

```
-A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  
          Places a line containing a group separator (--) between 
          contiguous  groups  of  matches.          
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU awk` you can do:

```
gawk -v RS='</Car>' 'NR==3 && $0=$2' inputFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/<Car>/{x;/.\{2\}/{x;$!{n;p};q};s/.*/&./;x}' infile
```

This is using the hold space to count.
Each time it encounters a line matching `<Car>` it e`x`changes buffers and checks if there are exactly *N-1* occurrences of a character in the hold buffer. If the check is successful it e`x`changes again, and if not on the last line, it pulls in the `n`ext line and `p`rints the pattern space then `q`uits.
Otherwise it just adds another `.` char to the hold space and e`x`changes back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple command line solution.

```
grep -F -A1 '<Car>' filename | grep -E -v '<Car>|--' | tail -n +3 |head -n +1
```

If you change the value of +3 after `tail`, you can specify any nth line.

Comment: Not sure why you added the tags, sed, awk, etc.
If you want a solution using a specific app, utility then you should specify this in question or title.