# Print contents of a file only after last occurrence of a token?

Tags: text-processing, grep, gnu

I have long-running programs that can restart their internal state. I want to see the log file entries only for the most recent state (to load into `vim`'s quickfix). How can I show all lines after the *last* occurrence of the string `STARTING SESSION`?

My current solution (log files are sometimes gigabytes long, so I never look at more than the last 5000 lines):

```
tail -n5000 logfile.log | grep -B5000 -v -e 'STARTING SESSION'> shortened.log
```

This works well when sessions produce a lot of logging, but if I have shorter logs with many restarts, it includes multiple sessions.

Essentially, I want something like a `--reverse` flag that would make grep search from the end of the file instead of the start:

```
grep --reverse --after-context=5000 --max-count=1 'STARTING SESSION' logfile.log
```

**Notes:**

*The question is similar to [Print line after nth occurrence of a match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115224/print-line-after-nth-occurrence-of-a-match), but I want the last occurrence.*

*The problem is almost the same as [Getting text from last marker to EOF in POSIX.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/getting-text-from-last-marker-to-eof-in-posix-2) except that I don't have a POSIX requirement and my files are large. I'd prefer efficient solutions with GNU utils (I'm using `mingw64`).*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting text from last marker to EOF in POSIX.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/getting-text-from-last-marker-to-eof-in-posix-2)

Answer (score 18):

Reverse the file, display it until the first occurrence, and reverse the output again:

```
tac logfile.log | sed '/STARTING SESSION/q' | tac
```

[`tac` is efficient when given a regular (seekable) file to process](https://serverfault.com/q/663038/268281), and since `sed` exits as soon as it sees the start line, the whole pipeline will only process the end of the log file as far as necessary (rounded up to `tac`’s, `sed`’s, and the kernel’s buffer sizes). This should scale well to large files.

`tac` is a GNU utility. On non-GNU systems, you can often use `tail -r` to do the same.

If the log file doesn’t have a “STARTING SESSION” line at all, this won’t produce the same behaviour as your `grep`: it will output the complete log file. To avoid this, a variant of [Kusalananda’s approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666175/86440) can be used instead:

```
tac logfile.log | sed -n '/STARTING SESSION/{H;x;p;q;};H' | tail -n +2 | tac
```

The `sed` expression looks for “STARTING SESSION”, and when matched, append the current line to the hold space, swaps the hold space with the pattern space, outputs it and exits; any other line is appended to the hold space. `tail -n +2` is used to skip the first blank line (appending the pattern space to the hold space adds a leading newline).

Answer (score 5):

Using `sed` [without `tac`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666166/116858):

```bsh
sed \
    -e '/STARTING SESSION/h' \
    -e '//,$ { //!H; }' \
    -e '$!d' \
    -e x logfile.log
```

or, using `;` between expressions on a single line,

```bsh
sed '/STARTING SESSION/h; //,$ { //!H; }; $!d; x' logfile.log
```

Annotated variant:

```
# If this line matches our trigger, save buffer in hold-space (overwrites).
/STARTING SESSION/ h

# In the range from the trigger to the end, append buffer to hold-space,
# but only if the current line isn't the trigger.
# (// re-uses the most recent expression)
//,$ { //!H; }

# If we're not at the end, restart with the next line without outputting anything.
$! d

# At the end, swap the hold-space into the buffer.
x

# (buffer is implicitly printed)
```

Summary:  This `sed` script saves all lines between the trigger and the end of the document in the hold-space of `sed`.  Whenever the trigger is found, the hold-space is cleared.  At the end, the hold-space is outputted.

If the trigger is not found, no output will be produced.

Note too that this will by necessity read through the entire file.

---

A similar approach with `awk`:

```bsh
awk '
    /STARTING SESSION/ { delete hold; i = 1 } 
    i { hold[i++] = $0  } 
    END { for (j = 1; j < i; j++) print hold[j] }' logfile.log
```

Here we'll start collecting data in the `hold` array once we have found our trigger (when we set `i` to one the first time).  We  delete the collected data and reset `i` down to one each time we hit the trigger.

At the end, all collected lines are outputted.

The `delete hold` statement is not strictly needed.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that both these approaches involve reading the complete log file, which might be a problem given that “log files are sometimes gigabytes long”.

Comment: @StephenKitt Ah, correct. I presume that `tac` is smarter and does some sort of chunking of the input.

Comment: Yes, if it can seek in its input, it reads from the end, 8KiB at a time.